# Created lambda resource based policy statement using Terraform but it does not show in AWS Lambda Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

Here's the terraform script snippet I used to create a lambda resource based policy

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_eventbridge_execution" {
  statement_id   = "AllowExecutionFromEventBridge"
  action         = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name  = aws_lambda_function.this.arn
  principal      = "events.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn     = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.this.arn
  qualifier      = aws_lambda_alias.latest.name
  source_account = local.aws_account_id
}

resource "aws_lambda_alias" "latest" {
  name             = "latest-version"
  description      = "An alias to the latest version of the lambda function."
  function_name    = aws_lambda_function.this.function_name
  function_version = "$LATEST"
}
```

My problem is that once I perform terraform plan and apply, I'm not seeing this when I look for the resource based policy via AWS Lambda Console.

[image: Resource-based policy statements shows no policy statements]

Does anyone have any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking at the correct lambda function?

Comment: Yes, I've added an output to my script which prints the ARN of the lambda function. I copied the ARN and did a find on the Lambda AWS Console against the Lambda function I'm looking at and the ARN matches.

Comment: And do you check the correct function version?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. I was looking at the permissions tab when I first land on the lambda function via AWS console. I currently have 2 versions. Looking at version 1 and 2 I see resource based policy is empty. However, when I looked into "aliases" and checked against the alias I created called "latest", the permissions tab there shows the resource based policy. Since my alias is linked to the latest deployment version, does this imply that the latest version will always have the permission applied?

Comment: Yes, as you create the policy for `aws_lambda_alias.latest.name`. If you don't mined I will provide the answer. Off course, you can change alias to point to a different version if you want.

Comment: Yes, that's fine, thanks. I have also added the aws_lambda_alias script to allow others to understand this more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `allow_eventbridge_execution` policy has been created for `aws_lambda_alias.latest.name`, so you have to check the permissions for that **alias**.